# Sssigning values to structs

Tags: arduino

I have a problem that i can't solve in my code.

Steps:

1. Create a struct with the year, month, day and other information.
2. Initialize these values through the serial.

But I am getting the following result - 'data' was not declared in this scope -
I do not know what is the problem, I believe is a syntax problem.

Sorry, I'm learning to work with structs.

I am grateful if someone can help me. I'm using Arduino.
Thanks

```
void setup_clock(){
  UtlTime = 0;
  second= 0;
  minut = 0;
  hour = 0;
  int turn = 1;

  if (turn == 1){
    int i = 0;
    typedef struct {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    float energy;
    } datas;
    datas data[10];
    turn++;
  }
  Serial.println("Minut: ");
  while(minut== 0){
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
      minut= Serial.parseInt();
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Hour: ");
  while(hour == 0){
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
      hour = Serial.parseInt();
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Month: ");
  while(data[0].month == 0){
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
        data[0].month = Serial.parseInt();
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Year: ");
  while(data[0].year == 0){
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
      data[0].year = Serial.parseInt();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datas data[10];` is a local variable and cannot be accessed from anywhere except for the `if` block. Define the struct and `data` elsewhere, say, just after `void setup_clock(){`.

Comment: Hi, MileCAT. And if I want to use data [0] .energy in another function?
for example: data [0].energy = 10;
How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Pass the data properly. It may be done by making `data` global or passing `data` as arguments for the function that wants it.

Comment: Okk. I'll try. Thanks a lot!